# How do I enlarge a graph a Masterpane using Zedgraph?

Tags: c#, graph, zedgraph

I would like, if I click on any graph, so that the selected chart increased or switched to a new window.

I tried to use the code of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19376381/2573395) to the question [How to select and enlarge a Masterpane in Zedgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952268/how-to-select-and-enlarge-a-masterpane-in-zedgraph)

**But I get an error:**

```
//Zedgraph control 
var zgc = Apprefs.Zedgraph;
```

*Error  1   The name 'Apprefs' does not exist in the current context*

[More in FIG.](http://s1.postimg.org/rwnk33w2n/V_st_i_ek.png)

[I used ZedGraph chart.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET)

Comment: Do you have a control in your application? What is it called? Is it called `Apprefs`? If you only copied/pasted the source code from that answer, and not modified it to the names of controls and and member names in your project, that will probably be the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. I created a graph

   public void CreateChart(ZedGraphControl zg1)
       {
           MasterPane master = zg1.MasterPane;
           master.PaneList.Clear();

   ```
       //Title of graph
       master.Title.IsVisible = true;
       master.Title.Text = SPolohaE+"E----"+SPolohaN+"N";
       master.Margin.All = 10;

       /*Background collor*/
       master.Fill = new Fill(Color.Blue, Color.LightBlue, 45.0f);

       GraphPane pane1 = new GraphPane();

       /*New list for graph*/
       PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();

       string date, time, y;
       double Y_axis, X_axis;
       /*load data row to row*/
       for (int rows = 0; rows < pocet_Radku-1; rows++)
       {
               /*load data from datagridview*/
               date = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
               time = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
               y = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

               Y_axis = double.Parse(y);
               string[] datum = date.Split(' ');
               DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(datum[0]+" "+time);
               /*Create X axis*/
               X_axis = (double) new XDate(dt);
               /*add to list data*/
               list1.Add(X_axis, Y_axis);
       }

       /*Type of X axes*/
       pane1.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;

       pane1.Title.Text = "Teplota 1"; //Title of char
       LineItem Graf1 = pane1.AddCurve("", list1, Color.Black, SymbolType.Diamond);

       //Add graph
       master.Add(pane1);

       //Set graph
       using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
       {
           master.SetLayout(g, true, new int[] { 3, 3, 2 });   /
       }

       /*init axes*/
       zg1.AxisChange();
       zg1.Invalidate();
   ```

   }

If I write here:

```
public void CreateChart(ZedGraphControl zg1)
{     
     var zg1 = Apprefs.Zedgraph;
..........
```

**So my Visual Studio word 'Apprefs' or not offered.**